# What's wrong to reset std::unique_ptr to pointer to array?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I see some code snippet like below:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> mCache;
mCache.reset(new uint8_t[size]);
```

Someone told me there are some problems with this code.
Can anyone give me some details?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: BTW, that code should read `auto mCache = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(size);`.  That is shorter and also exception-safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> mCache;`, when `mCache` is destroyed its [deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) will use `delete` to destroy the pointer being managed (if any), i.e. to deallocate memory for a single object. But after `mCache.reset(new uint8_t[size]);` what `mCache` manages is a pointer to array, that means it should use `delete[]` instead; using `delete` to deallocate memory for an array leads to UB.

The code could be changed to

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> mCache; // mCache is supposed to manage pointer to array
mCache.reset(new uint8_t[size]);   // safe now
```

Comment: another question, do we need to destroy mCache? Like mCache.reset().

Comment: @jiych.guru No. The destructor of `std::unique_ptr` will do the job for you.

Comment: Hi, I saw `std::unique_ptr<char> dirname(strdup(dirName.c_str()));` these days. It's not right in my opinion. Because the memory of strdup should be `free` to destroy but not delete. Is that right? Thank you.

Comment: @jiych.guru Yes. What you think is correct. We can provide a user-defined deleter for it.